# PostgreSQL information_schema.tables and TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions, race-condition

In PostgreSQL, I'm facing race conditions. My tables and schemas may be deleted by separate processes in the system. Using idiom *if schema and table exists, then read the contents* hence does not work in general, because the table may cease to exist in the middle of the statement.

One thing I don't understand is why `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` does not help. I'd suppose that I may expect consistent view of schemas and tables during my transactions, but I don't. Below is my Java code:

```
pgConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(/* ... */);
pgConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

PreparedStatement statement = pgConnection.prepareStatement(
                                 "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;");
statement.execute();

statement = pgConnection.prepareStatement(
               "SELECT ('myschema','config') IN " +
               "(SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables);");

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
result.next();
if(result.getBoolean(1)) {
    statement = pgConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT key,value FROM myschema.config;");

    result = statement.executeQuery();  // here I'm often getting an exception

    /* ... */
}
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "myschema.config" does not exist
```

How is that possible? I thought `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` will protect me from such conditions. Is that because dropping schemas is too specific operation to keep the isolation? Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Not all databases consider DDL to be "within" a transaction. (I'm not sure what pg's stance is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL statement `set transaction isolation level . . .` doesn't start a transaction. (Not in the sense you're interested in, anyway.)

Following your code, you'd write SQL statements either like this

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;
begin transaction;
...
```

or like this.

```
begin transaction isolation level serializable;
...
```

[Relevant PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-begin.html)

But you don't need serializable transactions for this. You can test by running psql in two terminal sessions.

```
sandbox=# begin transaction;
BEGIN
                                          sandbox=# begin transaction;
                                          BEGIN

sandbox=# select * from foo for update;
 foo_id 
--------
      1
(1 row)
                                          sandbox=# drop table foo;
                                          [waits . . .]
sandbox=# update foo set foo_id = 2;
UPDATE 1
sandbox=# select * from foo;
 foo_id 
--------
      2
(1 row)

sandbox=# commit;
COMMIT
                                          DROP TABLE
                                          sandbox=# commit;
                                          COMMIT

sandbox=# select * from foo;
ERROR:  relation "foo" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from foo;
```

Having said all that, designing a database in which tables and schemas might be *regularly* be dropped and (I presume) created seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I see that running two conflicting transtactions leads to freezing one of them in needed to avoid incostistency.. Now I also see how psql transactions work -- they block each other in place of collision.. Is that right? I did similar experiment with insertion of constraint-violating duplicities and it seems like yes.

Comment: Mostly right. Each transaction can set its own [isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/transaction-iso.html). Each transaction's isolation level tells PostgreSQL what it can tolerate from the effects of other concurrent transactions. In English, *waiting* is probably a better term than *freezing*; in English *freezing* suggests a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), but *waiting* does not.